# 'This site can’t provide a secure connection' Enable SSL configure for Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2019, iis-express, iis-express-10

As i have this project which has already **SSL Enabled** after **pressing F4** here is a snapshot below.

[image: Enable SSL]

As i update it with `https://localhost:58065/` on my **Web Project Url** it gives me this issue when the project runs.
[image]

As i have followed plenty of websites for help but nothing worked for me especially when i exported and imported and certificate file.
Even if i change the `http://localhost:58065/` to something like this `http://localhost:58061/`without **SSL** and `https://localhost:58065/` for **SSL** it still shows the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try another port, like this url

```
https://localhost:44337/
```

Me too had problem with 58061.

Try one of these:

44337,44338,44339, ..... 44399

The probable cause is that 44300-44399 are preconfigured by IIS Express installer with a test certificate, while other ports might not.

Comment: Thank you it worked like charm. for https://localhost:44337/

Comment: The probable cause is that 44300-44399 are preconfigured by IIS Express installer with a test certificate, while other ports might not. HTTPS does require a server certificate. https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/https-binding.html#background

Comment: Thank you @LexLi, You may be right, it is very sensible. I added your comment to my response.